# Securing Facebook Login through Javascript and PHP SDK

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**What I'm trying to achieve**

1. Javascript checks if the user is logged in or not, if so, send a code (either access_token or signedRequest) to PHP to securely deal with the logging in.
2. PHP will take the code from javascript and using the app_secret, will make sure the code given from javascript is valid.
3. Using the PHP SDK I would like to make all my Graph API calls with a appsecret_proof so I can turn on "require proof on all calls" in the FB App.

**Where I've got to**

1) I currently have javascript that initialises when the page loads, and assuming this particular user is logged in and authenticated in this case, I then have access to the `$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();` class, where I can then get the session and make calls in PHP, I could also pass in the access token directly using `$session = new FacebookSession('access token here');` - great!

2) I've got this snippet of PHP that will check the signedRequest property of the JS response that checks against the app_secret - great!

```
$signed_request = $_POST['signedRequest'];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
$secret = "mysecret"; // Use your app secret here

// decode the data
$sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
$data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);
// confirm the signature
$expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
  return null;
}

//this is the oAuth code.
echo $data['code'];
```

**Where I'm unclear**

I'm confused with point 3) in what I'm trying to achieve.

I want to utilise

> Secure Server-side Calls with appsecret_proof

The below snippet using the FB PHP SDK classes works great, it **does not send the appsecret_proof**. (if the result from the check in 2) is null, I can just bum out the script there, so that's fine.)

```
$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
$session = $helper->getSession();
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

I could curl that will have the appsecret_proof but is this not possible using the PHP SDK (it's cleaner through there).

```
curl \
  -F 'access_token=<access_token>' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=<app secret proof>' \
  -F 'batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/friends?limit=50"}]' \
  https://graph.facebook.com
```

**Maybe?**

Once I've completed 2) I should `getLongLivedSession()` on the JS SDK short-lived access_token and then `validate()` using the `Facebook\FacebookSession` namespace.  Is the validate the same as I did in 2)??  If I do it that way, can I still turn on the 'Require proof on all calls' in the FB App??

*Note: If you down-vote my question, please explain WHY, I'm still none the wiser as to why my last question was down-voted, and thus I can't improve.*

Comment: Using appsecret_proof should be the default with PHP SDK v4 in any case (unless you explicitly disable it). Have you actually tried this with the migration enabled in app dashboard and it failed?

Comment: Ah OK yes, the option has changed slightly to "Require App Secret", and when ticked to Yes it still works.  It must be using the app secret in the FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(Appid, AppSecret).  Is there still a case to use the check in step 2) ?  This still doesn't seem to use the appsecret_proof (which is a hash of the app_secret and access token) though.   Am I overthinking this or am I secure in my current setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there are two security features in the app in Settings->Advanced.

1. Require app secret for server API calls.  Although this isn't done explicitly, you enter the app secret here FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(Appid, AppSecret), so your app secret is sent through all the server api calls.
2. Server IP Whitelist - this will ensure that if your app secret is compromised, someone would still need to send the calls through your server (tricky!).

Secondly, code wise I run the following to help secure:

1. I run the check in 2) that I mentioned in my question.
2. I also use the $session->validate() method.
3. I then $session->extend the access token.

I believe that this is now secure.